# SQL Server Joining record based on max 7 days old

Tags: sql-server

The query that I've build does not fit the solution. I've tried many queries but can't get the result I want.

I have the following table

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ATC] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [PID] [varchar](7) NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [REG_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [ACTIVE] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_test_ACTIVE]  DEFAULT ((1))
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Example data

```
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[test] ([ATC],[PID],[NAME],[REG_DATE],[ACTIVE])
  VALUES ('A01','123456','TEST1','2016-08-31 00:00:00.000',0);
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[test] ([ATC],[PID],[NAME],[REG_DATE],[ACTIVE])
  VALUES ('A01','123456','TEST2','2016-09-01 00:00:00.000',0);
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[test] ([ATC],[PID],[NAME],[REG_DATE],[ACTIVE])
  VALUES ('A01','123456','TEST3','2016-09-02 00:00:00.000',0);
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[test] ([ATC],[PID],[NAME],[REG_DATE],[ACTIVE])
  VALUES ('A01','123456','TEST4','2016-09-03 00:00:00.000',0);
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[test] ([ATC],[PID],[NAME],[REG_DATE],[ACTIVE])
  VALUES('A01','123456','TEST5','2016-09-06 00:00:00.000',1);
```

Example Query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ATC, PID ORDER BY REG_DATE ASC) AS ROWNUM,* FROM [dbo].[test]
    WHERE ACTIVE=0
)
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, d2.REG_DATE, d1.REG_DATE),d1.NAME, d1.REG_DATE AS ACTIVE_REC_DATE, d2.REG_DATE AS NOTACTIVE_REC_DATE, d1.ACTIVE, d2.ACTIVE FROM [dbo].[test] as d1
LEFT JOIN CTE d2 ON d2.ATC = d1.ATC AND d2.PID = d1.PID
AND DATEDIFF(DAY, d2.REG_DATE, d1.REG_DATE) <= 7
WHERE d1.ACTIVE=1 AND d1.PID=123456;
```

Wanted result:

The record with column ACTIVE True (1) should contain (if the record exists) the REG_DATE of the not active previous record max 7 days old. Like:

```
(No column name)    NAME    ACTIVE_REC_DATE NOTACTIVE_REC_DATE  ACTIVE  ACTIVE
3   TEST5   2016-09-06 00:00:00.000 2016-08-31 00:00:00.000 1   0
```

Currently the query result contains multiple records because the are more records that will fall in the 7 days period. I need to join 1 record that will be the max 7 day old one.

I've used the ROW_NUMBER() with over partition by so I can use and identify the first record because I will be sorting ascending. This doesn't work when there is no previous records available or the previous records are older then 7 days
When there is no records to join is ignored can use INNER JOIN  or date columns at null

I hope I'm clear with my explanation.

Comment: Can you please also post your expected result table

Comment: Could you explain "This doesn't work when there is no previous records available or the previous records are older then 7 days"? - what should the result be in those circumstances?

Comment: @SandipPatel The expected reuslt is also in my explanation. It's below Wanted result:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, d2.REG_DATE, d1.REG_DATE),d1.NAME, d1.REG_DATE AS ACTIVE_REC_DATE, d2.REG_DATE AS NOTACTIVE_REC_DATE, d1.ACTIVE, d2.ACTIVE FROM [dbo].[test] as d1
OUTER APPLY 
(SELECT TOP 1 T1.* FROM dbo.test t1 WHERE t1.ATC = d1.ATC AND t1.PID = d1.PID and DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.REG_DATE, d1.REG_DATE) <= 7 order by t1.REG_DATE desc) d2
WHERE d1.ACTIVE=1 AND d1.PID=123456;
```

Comment: I needed to change the sorting order to ascending to get te wanted result. It seems the query work but I need to check certain scenarios. Thanks for your time. Never used APPLY before.

Comment: I wasn't sure if you needed the oldest or the newest date, but I'm glad it's been of help so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a single row for a `PID` by adding a filter on `ROWNUM` to your left join:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ATC, PID ORDER BY REG_DATE ASC) AS ROWNUM,* FROM [dbo].[test]
    WHERE ACTIVE=0
)
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, d2.REG_DATE, d1.REG_DATE),d1.NAME, d1.REG_DATE AS ACTIVE_REC_DATE, d2.REG_DATE AS NOTACTIVE_REC_DATE, d1.ACTIVE, d2.ACTIVE FROM [dbo].[test] as d1
LEFT JOIN CTE d2 ON d2.ATC = d1.ATC AND d2.PID = d1.PID
AND DATEDIFF(DAY, d2.REG_DATE, d1.REG_DATE) <= 7
AND d2.ROWNUM = 1
WHERE d1.ACTIVE=1 AND d1.PID=123456;
```

It's not clear from the question how the query should behave when no previous records from the last seven days exist.

Comment: The the joined column will be null in this case.

Comment: While looking for a solution  I did some test scenarios the rownum 1 was not always the correct row.